# Livecharts graphics

Tags: vb.net, graphics, livecharts

I'm using the Livecharts library to generate the graphics in my project, but I'm having trouble getting the values ​​to fill the graph, the code I have is the following

```
 grafico2.Series = New SeriesCollection From {
        New StackedRowSeries With {
            .Values = New ChartValues(Of Double) From {
                         67, 16, 41, 0, 7, 92, 3
                    },
            .StackMode = StackMode.Percentage,
            .DataLabels = True,
            .LabelPoint = Function(p) p.X.ToString(),
            .Title = "Faltantes"
        },
        New StackedRowSeries With {
            .Values = New ChartValues(Of Double) From {
                        23, 1, 1, 4, 2, 102, 0
                    },
            .StackMode = StackMode.Percentage,
            .DataLabels = True,
            .LabelPoint = Function(p) p.X.ToString(),
            .Title = "Respondidas"
        }
    }
```

If I put the values ​​of `New ChartValues ​​(Of Double) From {}`, the graph works well, but I want to fill it from a `For each` and that the graph is denamic.

I'm running out of ideas, you can help me